# Retrieve Private Ip of AWS FARGATE task using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, consul, aws-fargate

I have the requirement to extract the Private Ip of the Fargate task and need to pass the same in the container template as a parameter to the COMMAND so that the application can be run on that same IP.

I am trying the below command to run consul but it asks for IP.

```
"command": [
   "consul agent -server -data-dir=/consul/data -bootstrap -ui -client=0.0.0.0 -bind=0.0.0.0"
],
```

Instead of 0.0.0.0 need to pass the private IP address, and couldn't find any solution yet.

Have used the below terraform script but doesn't work:

```
 data "aws_network_interfaces" "consul_eni" {
    filter{
            values = [aws_subnet.private[0].id]
        }
      }
```

Then in the variable section, I am passing the data source as:

```
vars = {
         Interface_IP       = data.aws_network_interfaces.consul_eni.private_ip
       }
```

Getting the following error:

```
 line 20, in data "template_file" "consul_app":
 20:     Interface_IP       = data.aws_network_interfaces.consul_eni.ids

A data resource "aws_network_interfaces" "consul_eni" has not been declared in
the root module.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below option worked fine:

```
 -bind='{{ GetInterfaceIP "eth0" }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your use case. My understanding is, that you're running a task in Fargate and want to find out the IPv4 address of the task itself.

To achieve this you can use the Metadata service as described in the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4-fargate.html).

You can use a tool like `curl` to query the URL that is stored in the environment variable `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4` and then another tool like `jq` to parse the JSON response which looks like this:

```json
{
    "DockerId": "cd189a933e5849daa93386466019ab50-2495160603",
    "Name": "curl",
    "DockerName": "curl",
    "Image": "111122223333.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/curltest:latest",
    "ImageID": "sha256:25f3695bedfb454a50f12d127839a68ad3caf91e451c1da073db34c542c4d2cb",
    "Labels": {
        "com.amazonaws.ecs.cluster": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:cluster/default",
        "com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name": "curl",
        "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-arn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:task/default/cd189a933e5849daa93386466019ab50",
        "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-family": "curltest",
        "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-version": "2"
    },
    "DesiredStatus": "RUNNING",
    "KnownStatus": "RUNNING",
    "Limits": {
        "CPU": 10,
        "Memory": 128
    },
    "CreatedAt": "2020-10-08T20:09:11.44527186Z",
    "StartedAt": "2020-10-08T20:09:11.44527186Z",
    "Type": "NORMAL",
    "Networks": [
        {
            "NetworkMode": "awsvpc",
            "IPv4Addresses": [
                "192.0.2.3"
            ],
            "AttachmentIndex": 0,
            "MACAddress": "0a:de:f6:10:51:e5",
            "IPv4SubnetCIDRBlock": "192.0.2.0/24",
            "DomainNameServers": [
                "192.0.2.2"
            ],
            "DomainNameSearchList": [
                "us-west-2.compute.internal"
            ],
            "PrivateDNSName": "ip-10-0-0-222.us-west-2.compute.internal",
            "SubnetGatewayIpv4Address": "192.0.2.0/24"
        }
    ],
    "ContainerARN": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:container/05966557-f16c-49cb-9352-24b3a0dcd0e1",
    "LogOptions": {
        "awslogs-create-group": "true",
        "awslogs-group": "/ecs/containerlogs",
        "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
        "awslogs-stream": "ecs/curl/cd189a933e5849daa93386466019ab50"
    },
    "LogDriver": "awslogs"
}
```

The array under Networks has information about all the network interfaces attached to your task.

Comment: Adding below option worked fine:                                                                                                          
        bind='{{ GetInterfaceIP "eth0" }}'

Answer (score 0):

Consul supports using [go-sockaddr](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-sockaddr) templates in the `-bind` and `-client` flags. You can specify the addresses as `-client="{{ GetPrivateIP }} -bind="{{ GetPrivateIP }}"` which will cause Consul to bind to the first private IP address on the default interface (i.e., interface with the default route).

See https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_bind for more go-sockaddr examples.